# Jesse and Cookies

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, object-oriented, programming-challenge

Jesse loves cookies. He wants the sweetness of all his cookies to be greater than value `K`. To do this, Jesse repeatedly mixes two cookies with the least sweetness. He creates a special combined cookie with:

> ```
> sweetness = (1 * Least sweet cookie + 2 * 2nd least sweet cookie).
> ```

He repeats this procedure until all the cookies in his collection have a sweetness `>= K`. 
You are given Jesse's cookies. Print the number of operations required to give the cookies a sweetness `>= K`. Print `-1` if this isn't possible.
(See the online challenge on [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jesse-and-cookies).)

```
public class Solution {
    private static int N;
    private static int requiredSweetness;
    private static int[] sweetness;

    private static class Cookie {
        private final int sweetIndex;
        Cookie(int sweetIndex) {
            this.sweetIndex = sweetIndex;
        }
    }

    private static int solve() {
        // base case handling here to avoid creation of
        // expensive data structures.
        if (N == 1) {
            if (sweetness[0] >= requiredSweetness) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        PriorityQueue<Cookie> pq = new PriorityQueue<Cookie>(N, new Comparator<Cookie>() {
            public int compare(Cookie c1, Cookie c2) {
                return c1.sweetIndex - c2.sweetIndex;
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            pq.offer(new Cookie(sweetness[i]));
        }

        int count = 0;
        while (pq.size() > 1 && pq.peek().sweetIndex < requiredSweetness) {
            Cookie c1 = pq.poll();
            Cookie c2 = pq.poll();
            int sweetness = c1.sweetIndex + 2 * c2.sweetIndex;
            pq.offer(new Cookie(sweetness));
            count++;
        }
        if (pq.size() == 1 && pq.poll().sweetIndex < requiredSweetness) {
            count = -1;
        }
        return count;   
    } 

    private static void readInput() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        N = s.nextInt();
        sweetness = new int[N];
        requiredSweetness = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sweetness[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // part of the online coding where the code was
       // successfully submitted only after exhaustive test cases.
        readInput();
        System.out.println(solve());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this remind me of Huffman?

Comment: You may check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317912/1856618

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Unnecessary abstraction

An object containing a single field is suspicious.
You can eliminate the `Cookie` class,
and use simple integers instead.
That will also simplify the creation of the priority queue,
as you will no longer need a custom comparator.

#### Simplify condition

This condition could be simpler:

> ```
> if (pq.size() == 1 && pq.poll().sweetIndex < requiredSweetness) {
>     count = -1;
> }
> ```

Instead of polling, you could just `peek`,
which is cheap,
and the size doesn't really matter anyway.

Also, changing the value of `count` is not natural,
as -1 is not really a count, but a special value.

I would rewrite this condition as:

```
if (pq.peek().sweetIndex < requiredSweetness) {
    return 1;
}
```

#### Remove unnecessary pedantry

This code doesn't spare a lot of resources:

> ```
> // base case handling here to avoid creation of
> // expensive data structures.
> if (N == 1) {
>     if (sweetness[0] >= requiredSweetness) {
>         return 0;
>     } else {
>         return -1;
>     }
> }
> ```

Although it saves you from the creation of a `PriorityQueue`,
at the cost of several extra lines, and repeated use of the special -1 value.
You can delete this snippet and the program will still work,
this special treatment is premature optimization and its benefits are smaller than its drawbacks.

#### Simplify `PriorityQueue` creation

This is verbose:

> ```
> PriorityQueue<Cookie> pq = new PriorityQueue<Cookie>(N, new Comparator<Cookie>() {
>     public int compare(Cookie c1, Cookie c2) {
>         return c1.sweetIndex - c2.sweetIndex;
>     }
> });
> ```

First of all, use the diamond operator `<>` when possible.

Secondly, Hacker Rank supports Java 8,
so you can replace the anonymous comparator with a lambda expression:

```
PriorityQueue<Cookie> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(N, (c1, c2) -> c1.sweetIndex - c2.sweetIndex);
```

You can go one step further and replace with `Comparator.comparingInt`:

```
PriorityQueue<Cookie> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(N, Comparator.comparingInt(c -> c.sweetIndex));
```

#### Prefer a for-each loop

When initializing the priority queue,
it's better to use a for-each loop instead of a counting loop.

#### Naming

`sweetIndex` in `Cookie` is a misleading name.
When I saw the `int[]` array of `sweetness`,
I thought there might be a relation with the array indexes.
But that's not the case,
it's really just about the sweetness of cookies,
so I'd call it that.
It will make this condition more natural and therefore easier to read:

```
while (pq.size() > 1 && pq.peek().sweetness < requiredSweetness) {
```

It's a minor thing, but `c1` and `c2` here are also not great:

> ```
> Cookie c1 = pq.poll();
> Cookie c2 = pq.poll();
> int sweetness = c1.sweetIndex + 2 * c2.sweetIndex;
> ```

I'd rename them to `smallest` and `second`.

Comment: Once again a lot of fruitful advice. But I have to disagree on one thing that sometimes its better to name things and have types, `Cookie` seems a valid abstraction for readability and for flexibility too.